# Derivative of internal energy with respect to pressure at a constant volume

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, pressure, temperature, volume

I need to obtain the derivative of internal energy $U$ w.r.t. pressure $p$ at a constant volume $V$. Realizing that $\mathrm{d} U = T \mathrm{d} S - p \mathrm{d} V$, I rewrite
$$
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)_V = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial p} \right)_V
$$

The first term is equal to $T$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V = T
$$

For the second term I used
$$
\mathrm{d} U = T \mathrm{d} S - p \mathrm{d} V
$$
again, from which
$$
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V = T, \quad \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \right)_S = - p
$$
and therefore
$$
\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial S} \right)_V = -\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_S \quad \implies \quad \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial p} \right)_V = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial S} \right)_V} = - \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_S} = - \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_S
$$

So far, we have
$$
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)_V = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \right)_V \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial p} \right)_V = - T \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_S
$$

For $(\partial V/\partial T)_S$ I use
$$
\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right)_z \left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \right)_x \left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)_y = -1
$$
with $x = V$, $y = T$ and $z = S$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_S \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial S} \right)_V \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T = -1
$$

Using the definition for the heat capacity at constant volume, we get
$$
C_V = \left( \frac{\partial Q}{\partial T} \right)_V = T \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_V \quad \implies \quad \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial S} \right)_V = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial T} \right)_V} = \frac{1}{C_V / T} = \frac{T}{C_V}
$$

For $\left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T$ I use Helmholtz free energy
$$
\mathrm{d} F = - p \mathrm{d} V - S \mathrm{d} T
$$
so
$$
\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial V} \right)_V = - p, \quad \left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial T} \right)_S = - S
$$
therefore
$$
\left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T = \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right)_V
$$
and for the last time
$$
\left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right)_V \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_p \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \right)_T = -1
$$
with
$$
\alpha = \frac{1}{V} \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_p \quad \implies \quad \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_p = \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_p} = \frac{1}{\alpha V}
$$
and
$$
K_T = - \frac{1}{V} \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \right)_T \quad \implies \quad \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \right)_T = - K_T V
$$
and therefore
$$
\left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T = \left( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right)_V = - \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_p \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial p} \right)_T} = \frac{\alpha}{K_T}
$$
going back to
$$
\left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_S = - \frac{1}{\left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial S} \right)_V \left( \frac{\partial S}{\partial V} \right)_T} = - \frac{1}{(T/C_V) (\alpha/K_T)} = - \frac{C_V K_T}{\alpha T}
$$
and going back to the internal energy...
$$
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)_V = - T \left( \frac{\partial V}{\partial T} \right)_S = - T \left( - \frac{C_V K_T}{\alpha T} \right) = \frac{C_V K_T}{\alpha}
$$

However, the formula should be
$$
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)_V = \frac{C_p K_T}{\alpha} - \alpha V T
$$

My question is: **how do I obtain the second formula as quickly as possible without using Mayer's relation** $C_p - C_V = (\alpha^2/K_T) V T$?

P.S. I also found a quicker way to obtain the formula with $C_V$
$$
\left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial p} \right)_V = \left( \frac{\partial U}{\partial T} \right)_V \left( \frac{\partial T}{\partial p} \right)_V = C_V \frac{K_T}{\alpha} = \frac{C_V K_T}{\alpha}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$dH=dU+pdV+Vdp=C_pdT+V(1-\alpha T)dP$$So, $$dU=C_pdT-pdV-V\alpha Tdp$$The rest is basically what you've already done with your second method.

Comment: Would you please explain how we get the first equation? I don't quite see the line of reasoning...

Comment: The first equation for dH is derived in every thermo book.  The derivation starts from dH=TdS+Vdp.  Then we express dS in terms of partial derivatives with respect to T and p.  Then the Maxwell equation is used to express partial S with respect to p in terms of partial V with respect to T.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The Maxwell relation I alluded to starts from dG=-SdT+Vdp

Comment: It does. So since you express dS in terms of dT and dp, you actually almost do a derivation of Mayer's relation (which also uses dS expressed via dT and dp instead of dT and dV)...

Comment: Actually, this relationship is more fundamental than Mayer's relation, and Mayer's relation is typically derived from it, rather than the other way around.